# scapy independent layers, no encapsulation

Tags: python, scapy

I try to create a protocol, and I have some understanding problems. I
created a class for every layer. Then I created some methods that build
the packets for me, by stacking the layers one above the other.

When I create a packet:

```
a=Foo()/Bar() (or a=test())
```

I get something like:

`<Foo  | <Bar  |>>`, this means, to my understanding that the
packets are encapsulated (like for example `IP()/ICMP()` where it makes
sense). Now, my problem is that I want to have something more like:

```
<Foo |> <Bar |>
```

what am I doing wrong? Here follows the code I use (simplified version):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy").setLevel(1)
from scapy.all import *

class Foo(Packet):
    name = "Foo packet"
    fields_desc = [ 
                ByteField("foo1", 0x23)
                ]   


class Bar(Packet):
    name = "Bar packet"
    fields_desc = [ 
                ByteField("bar1", 0x42)
                ]   

def test():
    a=Foo()
    b=Bar()
    return a/b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    interact(mydict=globals(), mybanner="test-env")
```

Now, I'm not sure if "/" is the correct operator for this case. How
would I do it in a better way? In my protocol the layers are independent
and not encapsulated.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want `Bar` inside `Foo`, I don't understand why you aren't using a list... for instance this is a list of two pings to 10.2.2.2... `[IP(dst="10.2.2.2") / ICMP(), IP(dst="10.2.2.2") / ICMP()]`

```
sr([IP(dst="10.2.2.2") / ICMP(), IP(dst="10.2.2.2") / ICMP()])
Begin emission:
........................*Finished to send 2 packets.
......*
Received 32 packets, got 2 answers, remaining 0 packets
(<Results: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:2 Other:0>, <Unanswered: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>)
>>
```

Or in your case... `return [a, b]`.  This would provide two distinct encapsulations, instead of them stacked in a protocol hierarchy